# Galaxy S2 9100 Apps Sms download or not notification in China

Tags: applications, sms, notifications

I recently bought a Samsung Galaxy S2 GT-I9100 in China. It is a great phone for apps, but I constantly get notifications via sms for new apps mostly in Chinese.

If I click on it, it says install or cancel. Now I don't mind doing this 20 times a day, but the real annoying thing is it keeps making my SMS notification noise, so I dash to my phone, only to realise that it is another app, which I don't want.

Can anyone help me stop receiving these app request sms things? I am starting to question whether or not it is because I live in China, as my Sony Ericsson Xperia is the 1st version, which I bought in the UK, doesn't do this. Maybe because it was the early days of Android?

Comment: Are you talking about push messages? Is your service provider sending them?

Comment: SMS noise is not the same as SMS. Any number of apps can use the same notification sound as your messaging app. Are they being saved in your inbox? And compare the apps you have installed on your GS2 vs your Xperia, maybe you can find a rogue app that is responsible for this.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an SMS/Push message sent by your carrier in China.

I would suggest you contact your carrier, and ask them if they are sending these - and ask them if they can be stopped.

You can use [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.byq.airblocke) to block these if your carrier won't.